# Push a rebased branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-push

I have a little situation here. I rebased a dev branch, and tried to push it, but it was rejected (non-fast-forward)... Since I don't know why, I come to you...

What I did:

```
git checkout dev
git rebase G
# Here, I had to manually merge some files

# Result (in gitk) was :
#       A---B---C remote/dev   A'---B'---C' dev
#      /                      /
# D---E---F------------------G---H remote/master

git push remote dev
```

Any idea why my push is "non-fast-forward" and thus rejected ?

Comment: Try to pull remote/dev before, I think you should merge locally, not remotely (In other words the remote branch should be integrated in yours, not yours in the remote one)

Comment: @Vince: pulling (merging) the remote will merge the old history. History the OP probably wants to get rid of

Comment: yeah, you're right, but merge strategy is configurable. I suppose @knitl solution works anyway.

Comment: @Vince: yeah, they are configurable, but most (all?) merge strategies will record both parents of the merge, so the old history is recorded in the merge commit.

Comment: how is that bad? I think there is a way to know which has been chosen and the code before the rebase is probably interesting as well (it might just be a different use-case)

Comment: It's bad because it is dead/unused (and probably duplicated!) history

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not fast-forward, **because you did a rebase**. `rebase` takes a bunch of commits and creates new commits from them (possibly in a different location in the commit DAG). Please make sure that you understand all the implications of running `git rebase` before actually doing so. Not being able to fast-forward is one of these implications.

Rebasing published history is generally considered a bad idea. If you really must rebase your branch and push it, pass the `-f` flag to git push, or prepend your refspec with a `+` (`git push remote +dev`).

Other people who have cloned your repository and worked an that branch will have to do the same rebase, or you will merge old history the next time you merge from one of your contributors.

---

Elaborating on fast-forward:

From your graph this is easily visible. Fast-forward basically only ever appends commits to history. Each commit is uniquely identified by its commit hash. The commit hash gets computed over the commit contents as well as the history of the commit. This means that commits with different ancestors/parents are going to have a different hash by definition.

If you take a number of commits and plug them to a different location in the DAG they will describe a different history and will get a new commit hash (commit times were also updated, but that's not the point here). It's therefore not possible to *fast-forward* because it's not *append-only* anymore. Additionally you will be unable to access the old commits (without resorting to the reflog) after rebasing and pushing the result.

Another way to think about this: your push will not append commits to the old (`remote/dev`) branch, but append the commits elsewhere (commit `G`).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. What I want is to apply F and G to my dev branch. From what you say, I understand I'd rather merge than rebase, something like `git merge G` from dev. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes right. If you want G (and all of its history) you must run `git merge G` from your `dev` branch.